# rake "unknown type" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I can't run `rake db:migrate` on my rails project. I get this error:

```
/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:27: [BUG] unknown type 0x22 (0xc given)
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
...
# several lines of traceback here
...
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[1]    2610 abort      rake db:migrate
```

([full traceback](http://pastie.org/3116425))

I've tried installing rake=0.8.7, setting my rails project's Gemfile to use rake=0.8.7, but I still get the same "uknown type" error.

Migration file:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your migration file? Looks like you're running Rails 3.0.5 on Ruby 1.9.2. Correct?

Comment: Yes, Rails 3.0.5. I'm following a book and it uses 3.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post by Mark Aufflick](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2009/05/10/ruby-1-9-issue-on-mac-macports-bug-unknown-type-0x22-oxc-given), it could be due to how you installed Ruby.

I would recommend uninstalling Ruby and then re-installing it using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com).

Comment: I'm using RVM already.. `$ which rake` returns `/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
> bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

?